# Convert MySQL date and time columns from CST to GMT+2

Tags: mysql, date, time, timezone, convert-tz

I have two columns in a MySQL database table, which already had data in CST time format.

I want to convert those data from CST to GMT+2 (update current data).

Here's what I did using "CONVERT_TZ()" function as in this reference: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-convert_tz-function.php

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date` = (SELECT date(CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(`date`, ' ', `time`), '+16:00', '+02:00'))), `time` = (SELECT time(CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(`date`, ' ', `time`), '+16:00', '+02:00')))
```

But I get NULL result, as it doesn't recognize '+16:00'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it only understands time zones from `-12:00` to `+12:00`. What is `+16:00` supposed to be?

Comment: @Barmar The difference between GMT+2 and CST is 16 hours.

Comment: You don't give the difference, you give the original timezone and the new timezone. CST is `-06:00`

Comment: And the difference between them is 8 hours, not 16 hours.

Comment: @Barmar Aha, now I got it!